# how to access objects in list from other object's script in unity c#?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, distance

> I am trying to instantiate two types of objects and than check
>   distance between them.

I have public list in example cube:

```
    public List<GameObject> ba_list = new List<GameObject>();
```

I put first objects in it     `ba_list.Add(ga_bact);`
 than check distance from first object to second one in Update method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cube.GetComponent<spawn>().ba_list.Count; i++){             
  if (Vector3.Distance(cube.GetComponent<spawn>().ba_list[i].transform.position, gameObject.transform.position)<3)
            { do some animation}
```

> It does not give me any error, but it seems that for loop is not executed at all 
>    I checked it using print() method.

it is my second day trying to figure out what is wrong, I really need your help.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code snippet is quite unclear. What is `ga_bact`? Did you attached a `spawn` script to it? Where do you add `ga_bact` to `ba_list` in a method or inside `Start()`? You need to put more code, or at least more complete code so I can understand what you are doing, and to help you to find the issue. Also I would suggest to remove `cube.GetComponent<spawn>().ba_list.Count` from the for-loop, and instead save the count in a variable. If you put `cube.GetComponent<spawn>().ba_list.Count` in the for-loop the program will call `GetComponent()` every loop.

Comment: it works very well. Thank you!